# Using Xdebug & Zend Debugger Simultaneously?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, zend-studio, zend-debugger

Is it possible to run both debuggers within the same PHP installation simultaneously. They both use different ports so communication with the client IDEs/other apps wouldn't be an issue.

I ask only because using the Zend Debugger with ZendStudio has proven to be much easier (fewer steps to start/stop debugging from the browser), but I really like some of the profiling tools available that only work with XDebug. So in a nutshell, I would love to be able to have the best of both worlds if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.suspekt.org/2008/08/04/xdebug-203-stealth-patch/ (in particular the last comment) seems to indicate that the profiling parts of Xedebug will work fine alongside Zend Debugger, with the patch installed.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible - the simplest way on a development web server would be to run 2 different apache processes with different php.ini files referencing the different debugger modules

Comment: So simply enabling both of them within the same php.ini file wouldn't work?

Comment: No - the debugger modules conflict with each other.  But a nice workaround is too setup 2 apache instances on different ports, each using a different php.ini file, one loading zend debugger, the other loading xdebug.  You can then point each debugger at its relevant web server, and run both side by side.

Answer (score 0):

So, XDebug is known not to work with many Zend tools (I know Zend Optimizer for certain, I don't know about Zend Debugger but I wouldn't be surprised if XDebug has a built-in check for that).

Since you're running the debugger and profiler on a dev machine, I don't see why you can't maintain two separate ini files. Otherwise, you'll have to compile a custom version of yourself that bypasses the checks.